# Why do I have to prepend 'bundle exec' to my command today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler

Yesterday to run my tests I just needed `rspec` on the command line.

Today after doing a git pull and blah blah. I get this error

```
gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in 'block in setup': You have already activated rspec-support 3.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rspec-support 3.0.0. Prepending 'bundle exec' to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

And yes `bundle exec rspec` works and runs my tests. What is going on here "under the hood"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that in some point `rspec-support` gem was updated in your system. Maybe you did a `gem update`. But your app is using version 3.0.0 that is the reason for the message. You can update your bundle using `bundle update`. Usually the recommended way go avoid version collisions is to use `bundle exec`.

References:

- http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_exec.html
- http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Comment: To stop using bundle exec rake you can run bundle clean --force. This command will update your Gemfile.lock.